Reference request: If a pillar of your life suffers, it doesn't take long before the other pilars begin to suffer
I remember 20 years ago, I read a quote about morals. The author stated that it was important to keep each pillar of ones life in order, because if one pillar gets compromised, the others will begin to suffer shortly. The explanation that was given by the author was that the work and priorities that go into repairing the broken pillar causes the other pillars to get compromised.
The author might have used a different word than 'pillar', might have been 'column' or 'legs'. The author might have given some examples of what such pillars might represent. Say financials, health, security (but I don't remember exactly which ones the author mentioned). Have you heard this quote before (or something akin to it) and remember where it's from?

A search on DuckDuckGo found references to 1 Corinthians 12:26. Is that what you are looking for?

Not exactly where I saw it, but that's as good as it gets. If you put it a reply, I'll consider selecting it as the answer. What's the advantage of using duckduckgo compared to other search engines?

DuckDuckGo has a lot of protections for privacy.

A search on DuckDuckGo found references to 1 Corinthians 12:26. Is that what you are looking for?
